# Django migrations and docker containers

Tags: django, docker

How to handle Django migrations when using Docker.

For example, using containers in your dev environment, you have a Django app and other services, such as a Postgresql `db` container. Everything is docker pulled and docker-composed up.  Voila!

Now, you are asked to add features which require altering the database. No problem in dev.  You make some model changes, use `makemigrations` and `migrate` and all looks ok.

When pulling your new images to production your migrations don't jive with what's in the persistent `db` in the django_tables in prod and you can't run migrations without erroring out.

Anyone know how to make all this less painful.

Comment: add your docker-compose.yml file and DockerFile to question

Answer (score 3):

Running migration on docker container. suppose your compose file looks like

```
services:
  # cointainer for django app
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
```

## Use docker-compose run

Run command manually, The name of Django app container is `app`

```
docker-compose run app python manage.py migrate

# use if docker compose file name is other than `docker-compose.yml` 
docker-compose -f production.yml run app python manage.py migrate
```

---

## Use entrypoint.sh

Run automatically, every time when you `up` container.

Create a file name *entrypoint.sh* on project root and copy below command in it.

```
python manage.py migrate --noinput
```

In DockerFile copy *entrypoint.sh* from your project folder into container `app`.

```
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
RUN chown app /entrypoint.sh
```

**Now there are 2 ways you can make *`entrypoint.sh`* run automatically**

Mention `ENTRYPOINT` in DockerFile itself.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Or you can mention it in docker-compose file with `command` keyword under `app`.

```
app:
   build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
   depends_on:
     - db
   # this will run after cointainer `up`
   command: /entrypoint.sh
```

Comment: Done all that.  The problems arise when you have all the migrations in your image.  Migrate runs when you  start the web container, but the djang_migrations file doesn't match your migrations.  You can get all sorts of errors.  There should be a standard formula for this haven't found one yet.

Comment: Add some error logs you are getting while running the migrations,  That will help to figure out what exactly happening wrong.

Comment: Facing the same issue as @Mitch. Migrations files in the docker container are not the same as on work folder on the local computer

Comment: @Mitch I realize this is a bit old but I am just jumping on the Docker bandwagon in a serious way and your problem is my first mental block. Having the migration file(s) for new feature X only in the docker sounds wrong. And reading the answers above no one seems to get it. The complete working code should reside safely in a GitHub or similar repo.

Answer (score 3):

We've been using Docker in dev and production for over a year now. If I understand your situation correctly the issue is that your production db schema is getting out-of-sync with your development schema over time.

What helped us is to have easily shippable snapshots of our production schema (with some test data) so when you build a dev image you're running with the production schema and creating migrations based on the prod schema. When you're satisfied that your schema-to-be-migrated to is solid, check those migrations into source control.

Deployment to prod is then shipping an image with those migrations guaranteed to apply cleanly to the prod schema.

Comment: From the description, it sounds like the problem might be to do with how migrations are being used.  We use the approach you describe, and enforce that once a migration has been shipped to production it becomes *immutable*.  Attempting to go back and edit migrations that have already shipped will always cause unnecessary headaches.

Comment: I'm at PyCon, and A Lee's suggestion appears to be what is typically done.